# How to add php code in JS file

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Im using yii framework to do web development , text are call from specific php file in order to help me exchange the language. Some how i have to add some message from JS file, but i still need the yii php to call the text . How to do that? bellow if my coding

I would like to change "English: 26 character","Chinese: 16 character" and "Other: 16 character".

Because in yii calling text from other php is something like this:

In the labels.php is like this:

(eg: 'englishchar'=>'English: 26 character')

So to call the text is like this:

```
eg:<?php echo Yii::t('labels','englishchar');?>


$(function () {
        $('#select_gametitle').change(function () {
            var k = $(this).val();

            if (k == "E") {
                $("#txtgametitle").attr("placeholder", "English: 26 characters").placeholder();
                $("#txtgametitle").attr('maxlength', '26');
            }
            else if (k == "C") {
                $("#txtgametitle").attr("placeholder", "Chinese: 16 characters").placeholder();
                $("#txtgametitle").attr('maxlength', '26');
            }
            else if (k == "O") {
                $("#txtgametitle").attr("placeholder", "Other: 16 characters").placeholder();
                $("#txtgametitle").attr('maxlength', '26');
            }
            });
                $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
        });
```

PHP code:

```
                           <div class="inputWrapper">
                            <div class="usetitle">* <?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'gametitle'); ?> :</div>
                            <select id="select_gametitle" name="select_gametitle" class="selectInput" style="width:369px;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'select_gametitle'); ?></option>
                                <option value="E"><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'english'); ?></option>
                                <option value="C"><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'chinese'); ?></option>
                                <option value="O"><?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'other'); ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <div id="err_select_gametitle" class="error"></div>
                                <input id="txtgametitle"  name="txtgametitle" type="text" class="textInput" style="width:352px;" placeholder=""  />

                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your PHP code so we can give you working examples?

Comment: If the file is a php file you can simply add <?php ... ?> between the quotes inside your javascript.

Comment: @icecub but the file is JS ... that why i asked

Comment: Well I'm not to formilliar with Yii. But I do know that if you need PHP data inside a JS file, ajax can be your answer. Basicly you just pull the data you need out of a PHP file into your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a global var inside  tags in your main layout file.

/view/layouts/main.php:

```
<?php 
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->clientScript->getCoreScriptUrl().'/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/styles.css" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>

    <?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/css/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/css/style.css" />
    <script>
       eg:<?php echo Yii::t('labels','englishchar');?>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
```

Comment: dont really understand what u try to say

Answer (score 0):

You could add the script before the div, from PHP, for example:

```
<!--just add your script code-->
<script>
  $(function () {
    //your js code
    <?php echo "with text printed by php"); ?>
  });
</script>

<!--and now your html code, also with embedded PHP-->
<div class="inputWrapper">
    <div class="usetitle">* <?php echo Yii::t('labels', 'gametitle'); ?> :</div>
    <!--the rest of your div-->
</div>
```

Comment: php code and js script are separate into different file ... what i need is put php in js file ... not in php file

Comment: PHP code in js code is not possible. PHP runs on a server and JS runs on a user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could echo out the translate into a JSON.

```
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('test',
            'var lang =' . json_encode( array(
        'message1'=>Yii::t('app','Message 1'), 
        'message2'=>Yii::t('app','Message 2'),              
    )) . '; console.log(lang.word1)');

    $this->render('json');
```

Extending from this, you could use AJAX and JS template

Comment: can u explain more briefly ? how to put this on my JS file ?

Comment: You can't put PHP script into a Javascript file. From my example you can use to generate dynamic Javascript inside the PHP. Another way would be to use the renderPartial from the controller and pass it to the registerScript